Apex Batch Question
I am trying to create a batch process that creates records based on a list of strings that are passed to it.  I am struggling to return the list.  So in the start method I want to return the list of strings I have instead of using Database.getQueryLocator.  when I try to use the code below, I am getting an error,

Illegal conversion form List<String> to System.Iterable<List<String>>

Any help is greatly appreciated!!
public class censusUploadBatch implements Database.batchable<List<String>>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful{
    /* This process creates census records (this batch class is called when someone tries to upload a large census file, over 5000 records)
    */ 

    //global variables that need to be set
    public string fileName2;
    public List<String> base64Data2;
    //public string base64Data2;
    public Boolean deleteExisting2;
    public Boolean ignoreHeaderRow2;
    public Id censusId2;

    // wrapper list to capture errors    
    //List<errorDetailsWrapper> errorsWrapper = new List<errorDetailsWrapper>();

    public censusUploadBatch(String fileName, List<String> base64Data, Boolean deleteExisting, Boolean ignoreHeaderRow, Id censusId) {

      //  String data  = JSON.deserializeUntyped(base64Data).toString(); 
      // List<String> rows = data.split('\n');
      
        //set global veriables from the variables passed in
        fileName2 = fileName;
        base64Data2 = base64Data;
        deleteExisting2 = deleteExisting;
        ignoreHeaderRow2 = ignoreHeaderRow;
        censusId2 = censusId;
    }

    public Iterable<List<String>> start(Database.BatchableContext info) {
       return base64Data2;
    }
    
/*    public Database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context){
       // return this;
       return base64Data2;
    }
*/
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<List<String>> scope ) {      
        System.debug( JSON.serializePretty( scope ));       
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext contextx){
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, '4 c here is fileName2 ' + fileName2);
    }
}


could possibly be as simple as changing return base64Data2; to return base64Data2.iterator();

Also, for formatting code, the easiest way when you're pasting it from your clipboard is probably just to include three backticks \``on their own line both above and below the code block. Otherwise, you'd need to paste it, highlight it, then hit the{}` button to ensure that every line starts with at least 4 whitespace.

Thanks for responding!!  Unfortunately, that did not do it.

Change the return type to Iterable<String> and return what Derek suggested.

@PhilW List<String> is already an Iterable<String> (proof: Assert.isTrue((Object)new List<String>() instanceOf Iterable<String>); The main problem is the mix-up between using List<String> and List<List<String>> throughout the code.

Why do you use Batch? Why don't use Queueable or just a Future method?

public class censusUploadBatch implements Database.batchable<List<String>>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful{

Is telling Salesforce that you want a list of list of strings, so it expects:
public List<List<String>> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {

And:
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<List<String>> scope) {

Instead, you want to declare the base type that you're trying to use, in other words, just String:
public class censusUploadBatch implements Database.Batchable<String>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<String> scope) {

Or, if you really did mean a list of list of strings, you need to change all the places where you accidentally used List<String> instead of List<List<String>>.
